# Safest solvent for removing concrete stain

Tags: concrete, paint, stain, paint-removal, stain-removal

I’d like to remove Behr solid concrete stain from a patio. What would be the safest product for stripping it off? https://www.behr.com/consumer/products/floor-coatings-sealers-and-prep/concrete-stains/behr-premium-solid-color-concrete-stain

Comment: Safe for what/who?  Quite a few things will be safe for concrete, but you would need safety equipment to use them.  Safest for you will probably be a good pressure washer, no chemicals just water.

Comment: Tried a 3000 psi pressure washer by itself and it’s not practical for the large area. A handheld grinder would be faster. Looking for something to loosen it up.

Comment: Something safe enough to power wash into the grass.

Comment: Most strippers sold at stores should be on the safe side, as in open air, not drinking them safe.  Grass does add a complication.  I think there might be a few natural strippers, but even then I would want to water the grass very well to dilute.

Answer (score 1):

A walk-behind concrete grinder, most likely.

Comment: The dust from the concrete is not safe for the grass, so might need to cover the grass with plastic cover sheets.

Comment: Depends where you are. It's functionally artificial limestone, and in my area liming lawns is quite normal. In an alkali area that might be a problem. There should be slurry, not dust, anyway (water-lubricated process.)